# Only one column with primeng dataview

Tags: angular, layout, primeng, dataview

I'm trying to use PrimeNG dataview in my angular app.
Basically I copied this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dataview-demo
I just added some structure in my app (dataview is in a module instead of main component)
and I cannot put more than one column for the data. Everything is fine except the column display.
I know it's column by default, which we can see on Stackblitz.
I tried a lot of things with CSS, Bootstrap. Even removing it all.

I managed to shrink the grid item but the margin is basically impossible to remove. Anyone knows how to solve this ?

Even an equivalent, easier tool from another graphical library would help a lot.

Comment: You said that everything is fine, except the graphical display. Could you please provide an image of what you see. Also, the stackblitz seems to be broken. I just see this message in the display:
"Error in /~/src/app/app.module.ts (30:14)
Cannot use import statement outside a module". It is possible that is on my end, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turned out that I had custom component with Inputs for primeng, in my app. (the code has been given as training)

Because there is a custom component for this, there was a lot of CSS involved and everything went great when I used the component made for it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).